# Error en SELECT con BETWEEN entre un rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es el siguiente, estoy intentando mostrar una tabla con las personas que deben cancelar en el mes de enero o cualquier mes, eso lo hago de la siguiente forma:

Primero paso en un enlace el dato inicial via GET

```
<a href="calendario.php?dato=<?php echo date('01-m-Y');; ?>">
```

Ese dato lo recibo aqui y ejecuto mi consulta:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['dato'])){
   $dato2 = date('t-m-Y');
   $fecha = $_GET['dato'];

   $query = "SELECT * FROM students INNER JOIN inscritos ON 
   inscritos.id_student = students.id_students 
   INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion = 
   inscritos.id WHERE pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar BETWEEN '$fecha' AND 
   '$dato2'";

   $sql = $mysqli->query($query);

   while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><?php echo $row['names'] ?></td>
       <td><b><?php echo $row['monto'] ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $row['fecha_a_pagar'] ?></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
     <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

El resultado que obtengo de eso no es el deseado, me muestra todos los registros que tengo, osea todas las personas que estan registradas en el sistema. Y solo quiero mostrar los que la fecha a pagar este por ejemplo entre 01-01-2018 y 31-01-2018. Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Comment: hiciste un echo de las dos fechas ? vienen bien?

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer @gbianchi obteniendo esto fecha inicial = 01-01-2018 fecha final = 31-01-2018. No logro entender que es lo que pasa. Y en mi tabla los datos de fecha estan guardados en ese formato

Comment: Estan como date? deberiamos revisar si para mysql los datos al comparar fechas se pasan asi o de otra forma. no siempre el formato en que los ves por pantalla tiene que ver con el formato guardado...

Comment: en mi base de datos no. estan como text. fecha_a_pagar es de tipo text. Sera que hay problema con eso?

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta en sí: el código de la pregunta puede ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Comment: Si Alvaro. Pero con eso no hay problema porque es un sistema local. No esta hosteado. Es usado localmente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que estás usando `BETWEEN` con un campo inadecuado (lo cual es una pena y te podrá pasar una factura muy alta), la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) dice lo siguiente:

> If you use a string constant such as '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a
>   DATE, cast the string to a DATE.

O sea, que tendrás que hacer una conversión de tu cadena a fecha para hacer la comparación. Si la columna fuese del tipo `DATETIME` esta conversión no sería necesaria.

Prueba la consulta así:

```
SELECT * FROM students 
INNER JOIN inscritos ON inscritos.id_student = students.id_students 
INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion =  inscritos.id 
WHERE CAST(pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '$fecha' AND '$dato2';
```

Si en tu columna `fecha_a_pagar`tienes las fechas almacenadas en el formato `DD-MM-YYYY` estamos ante un despropósito total, porque MySQL almacena las fechas en formato `YYYY-MM-DD`. Entonces tendrás que reformatear todo para hacer una comparación correcta:

```
SELECT * FROM students 
INNER JOIN inscritos ON inscritos.id_student = students.id_students 
INNER JOIN pagos_estudiantes ON pagos_estudiantes.id_inscripcion =  inscritos.id 
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(pagos_estudiantes.fecha_a_pagar, '%d-%m-%Y')
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$fecha', '%d-%m-%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$dato2', '%d-%m-%Y');
```

---

**Nota:** Como ya señaló @AlvaroMontoro en un comentario, **tus consultas son vulnerables a la Inyección SQL.**

Comment: Cedano absoluta razón tienes, demasiado mal hecho lo del campo de fecha en text, groso error. Pero ya no puedo modificarlo debido a la cantidad de datos que tiene ya la tabla. De todas formas ha funcionado la segunda consulta con el STR_TO_DATE. Y lo de la inyeccion SQL lo tengo muy claro, pero como comente ese sistema esta siendo usado de manera local, no esta en la web. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta cedano

Comment: @AlejoMendoza si tienes privilegios para modificar la tabla recomendaría que lo hicieras con un plan de trabajo muy sencillo: 1. Copia de seguridad de la tabla; 2. Creación de una nueva columna del tipo `DATETIME`; 3. Volcado de la información de la columna del tipo `text` a esa nueva columna, eso sí, **formateando bien los datos en `YYYY-MM-DD`**, como acabamos de hacer, con `STR_TO_DATE`. Puedes hacer eso a través de una consulta que te haga todo el volcado; 4. Verificar en la nueva columna aquellas fechas que sean `0` o `NULL` (significará que en la columna antigua tenían un error)...

Comment: ... 5. Corregir el error (si es posible) en la nueva columna; 6. Borrar la columna antigua y **renombrar la columna nueva con el nombre que tenía la antigua**; 7. Si alguna vez hay duda con respecto a alguna fila, podrás consultar la copia de seguridad que has hecho para comparar los datos; 8. Corregir las consultas que hayas hecho teniendo que recurrir a procedimientos complicados debido a que la columna no era del tipo `DATETIME`. Haciendo eso, tendrás tus datos corregidos definitivamente.

Comment: Entiendo Cedano. Y me pondre a hacer eso que me dices! Muchas Gracias!